# Generic type parameter as variable

Tags: swift, generics, parameters

Is there a way to dynamically pass a type parameter to a generic swift class? The below is just for illustration purposes from a playground which gives the error: use of undeclared type 'button'

```swift
import Cocoa

class PrintNameOfClass<T: NSObject> {
    func printType() {
        print(type(of: T.self))
    }
}

let button = NSButton()
let test = PrintNameOfClass<button>()
test.printType()
```

Comment: try button.self

Comment: If I change to button.self I'm getting the following two errors: Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'ComparisonPrecedence' and Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PrintNameOfClass<NSObject>.Type' and 'NSButton'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's more reasonable to make the function generic rather than the class to be able to pass the *instance* `button`

```
class PrintNameOfClass {
    func printNameOfClass<T : NSObject>(of : T) {
        print(type(of: T.self))
    }
}

let button = NSButton()
let test = PrintNameOfClass()
test.printNameOfClass(of: button)
```

Comment: That works! Still looking as to whether there is way in the above example as in the actual code a lot of the methods already in place actually leverage the generic type parameter of the class.

Comment: The generic parameter in your example must be a **literal** type like `PrintNameOfClass<NSButton>()` because it's evaluated at compile time. It cannot be a dynamic type like `button.self`

Comment: Yes, a literal type absolutely works - my question is whether there is a way to use a dynamic type at all, maybe in a different way or not.

Comment: @Daniel no, that won't work, since all types must be known at compile time, so you cannot specialise a generic type with a type in runtime